# REST API search with URL parameters, testing works with some values but not others (all are valid entries)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

Im creating a web app to search a database of vases using Django/react. I've created an API view which takes URL parameters to search a vase record. When testing the API call some values work as expected, but others don't.
Here is my views.py:

```
class FilterVases(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = VaseSerializer 
    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Vase.objects.all()
        query_provenance = self.request.query_params.get('provenance_name')
        if query_provenance is not None:
            try:
                provenance = Provenance.objects.get(provenanceName=query_provenance)
                queryset = queryset.filter(provenance=provenance)
            except:
                pass
        inscription = self.request.query_params.get('inscription')
        if inscription is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(inscription=inscription)
        query_shape = self.request.query_params.get('shape_name')
        if query_shape is not None:
            try:
                shape = Shape.objects.get(shapeName=query_shape)
                queryset = queryset.filter(shape=shape)
            except:
                pass
        query_collection = self.request.query_params.get('collection_name')
        if query_collection is not None:
            try:
                collection = Collection.objects.get(collectionName=query_collection)
                queryset = queryset.filter(collection=collection)
            except:
                pass
        query_artist = self.request.query_params.get('artist_name')
        if query_artist is not None:
            try:
                artist = Artist.objects.get(artistName=query_artist)
                queryset = queryset.filter(artist=artist)
            except:
                pass
        fabric = self.request.query_params.get('fabric')
        if fabric is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(fabric=fabric)
        vaseID = self.request.query_params.get('vaseID')
        if vaseID is not None:
            queryset = queryset.filter(vaseID=vaseID)
        return queryset
```

and my models.py:

```
#define shape class
class Shape(models.Model) :
    shapeID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    shapeName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#define artist class
class Artist(models.Model) :
    artistID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    artistName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#define provenance class
class Provenance(models.Model) :
    ProvenanceID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    provenanceName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#define collection class
class Collection(models.Model) :
    collectionID = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    collectionName = models.CharField(max_length=100)

#define vase class
class Vase(models.Model):
    vaseID = models.CharField(max_length=10) 
    vaseRef = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    inscription = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    fabric = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,null=True)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=255,blank=True,null=True)
    technique = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    height = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True)
    diameter = models.FloatField(max_length=100,blank=True,null=True) 
    shape = models.ForeignKey(Shape, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    artist = models.ForeignKey(Artist, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    provenance = models.ForeignKey(Provenance, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def artist_name(self):
        return self.artist.artistName
    def collection_name(self):
        return self.collection.collectionName
    def provenance_name(self):
        return self.provenance.provenanceName
    def shape_name(self):
 

   return self.shape.shapeName
```

A few examples of parameter testing:
if i pass /?collection_name=collection name, i get the **expected** output of records containing collection name "collection name".
If i pass /?collection_name=Naples, i get all of records in the database returned- **unexpected**.
If i pass /?artist_name=python, i get the **expected** record containing the artist "python".
If i pass /?artist_name=artist name, i get the **expected** records containing "artist name".
if i pass /?artist_name=dirst painter, i get all records in the database returned- **unexpected.**
All of the parameters above are valid and have entries in the db, but only some return. The same thing is happening for shape_name and provenance_name. Strange and unexpected output.
Does anyone have any explanation as to what is happening?

Comment: I think that's happening: you get the all values and try to filter them in try-except block. Some values are probably break the try block that's why it's passing and it returns all values because program could not did any filter. Maybe you can try to print error in except part, then you can understant what's happening.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, i printed the error and discovered the values i was searching with had duplicates in the database in error.